# How to derive this equation. Combo of chain rule and product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm curious, why can't you use chain rule first? Why does product rule have to come first?

$$h(t) = (t+1)^{2/3} \cdot (2t^2-1)^3$$
$$h'(t) = (t+1)^{2/3} \cdot (3(2t^2-1)^2 \cdot 4t) + (2t^2-1)^3\cdot \frac{2}{3}(t+1)^{-1/3} \cdot 1$$
$$h'(t) = (t+1)^{2/3} \cdot (12t(2t^2-1)^2) + (2t^2-1)^3 \cdot \frac{2}{3}(t+1)^{-1/3}$$

How do I simplify from here? I'm not too sure how to pull out that $(t+1)$ since there is a mix of positive and negative integers. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Use [Feynman's Differentiation Trick](https://arcsecond.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/feynmans-differentiation-trick/). When $$f = u^a v^b w^c,$$ then $$f' = f \cdot (a u'/u + bv'/v + cw'/w).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no existing answers with positive score, I expand my comment into an answer.

$$
\begin{aligned}
h(t) &= (t+1)^{2/3} (2t^2-1)^3 \\
h'(t) &= h(t) \left[ \frac23 \frac{1}{t+1} + 3 \frac{4t}{2t^2 - 1} \right] \\
&= (t+1)^{2/3} (2t^2-1)^3 \cdot \left[ \frac23 \cdot \frac{1}{t+1} + 3 \cdot \frac{4t}{2t^2 - 1} \right] \\
&= \frac23 (t+1)^{-1/3} (2t^2-1)^3 + 12t (t+1)^{2/3} (2t^2-1)^2 \quad\text{(This line is redundant.)} \\
&= \frac23 (t+1)^{-1/3} (2t^2-1)^2 \left[ (2t^2-1) + 18t(t+1) \right] \\
&= \frac23 (t+1)^{-1/3} (2t^2-1)^2 (20t^2 + 18t -1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Remarks: I have left a redundant line in the answer to show that my calculations are consistent with the question body.

---

(Edit in response to OP's doubts.)

> Why can't you use chain rule first?  Why does product rule have to come first?

I would rather ask *how* to apply chain rule *first* in
$$(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x).$$
*What* $f$ and $g$ can be chosen?

The Chain Rule is applied on composite functions, but *first* $h$ is a *product* of two functions $f(t) = (t+1)^{2/3}$ and $g(t) = (2t^2 - 1)^3$.  Observe that both $f$ and $g$ are composite functions.  Consequently,

1. Apply the Product Rule on $h$ to get $h' = f'g + fg'$.
2. Apply the Chain Rule on both $f$ and $g$.

However, I *can't* find a trick neater than Feynman's one.

Comment: In the first line, when you derived $(2t^2-1)^3$, shouldn't that be ${4t}{2t^2 - 1}^2$

Comment: Did you apply the product rule correctly when you went from line 1 to 2?

Comment: @Jwan622 No, I'm using Feynman's trick.  Observe that in the third line, my results are the *same* as yours.

Comment: @Jwan622 I mean I forgot stuffs like product rules and chain rules and I just use Feynman's trick to give a quick and correct response.  Check [Wolfram's output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+(t%2B1)%5E%7B2%2F3%7D+(2t%5E2-1)%5E3).

Comment: Cool, I'll start from the third line since I haven't really learned or proved Feynman's trick to myself yet.

Comment: @Jwan622 Thanks for upvote and accept.  Actually the third line is *redundant*.  I misread your question as the "proof" of the last equality in the question body from the first equality, so I've included the third line.  You may skip that and focus on Feynman's trick.  My advice to pick up this trick is to start with *polynomials* first, then *rational functions* of polynomial, before mixing it up with transcendental functions like sin/cos/exp.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$h^3 (t)=g (t)=(t+1)^2 (2t^2-1)^9 $$

$$3h^2 (t)h'(t)=g'(t) $$

$$=2(2t^2-1)^8 (t+1)(20t^2+18t-1)$$

$$h'(t)=\frac 23 (2t^2-1)^2 (t+1)^{-\frac 13}(20t^2+18t-1) $$

Comment: When compare it with my answer, I can see that it's wrong.  More importantly, OP asks for derivation of $$h'(t) = (t+1)^{2/3} \cdot (12t(2t^2-1)^2) + (2t^2-1)^3 \cdot \frac{2}{3}(t+1)^{-1/3}.$$  Finally, if you have a question, you should start a new post.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: -1: With no response, I hope to draw your attention so that you can correct your answer.  The linked [Wolfram Alpha's output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+(t%2B1)%5E%7B2%2F3%7D+(2t%5E2-1)%5E3) may assist you.

Comment: my only issue with wolfram is that it sometimes doens't give me a step by step proof that I understand.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Now surely correct.